# Hello, I'm a. beginner at Django API and http GET Method doesn't work. It prints an error

Tags: python, django, http

In urls.py, which is in 'users' folder, which is containing migrations folder,
localhost: 8000 /users is scripted.
Then I typed http GET localhost:8000 on the command line after which Virtual environment had been activated.
But It prints this error.

> http: error: ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost',
> port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
> 0x10172bd60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61]
> Connection refused'))

while doing a GET request to URL: http://localhost:8000/

What's the problem? I've been stuck into this step so I couldn't go forward anymore.
Please give me some help!

Comment: Without seeing any relevant code, it is hard to help you. Also, we don't know what you mean by "localhost: 8000 /users is scripted" (and whether the spaces are really there, or just bad formatting of the question), or how you run your Django project.

Answer (score 1):

Possible things that are missing:

1. first you try and run `python manage.py runserver`
2. in your settings `ROOT_URLCONF='users/urls'` and then in your `users` folder,

have `urls.py` contain something like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def demo_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello world.")


urlpatterns = [
    path('', demo_view)
]
```

Now you can access `https://localhost:8000/` in your browser.

3. If you have a main folder for your app (eg. a `mysite` folder), then it has a `urls.py` where you'll need to include your `users/urls.py`.

then add to `mysite/urls.py`'s contents:

```
urlpatterns += [path('', include('users.urls'))]
```

Please be more specific with your question so people can give you better answer.

Comment: Thanks for advising me at the end line.
I'll try what you've suggested me. Take Care!

Comment: No problem 정민기, I hope it'll help